# try catch в анонимном выражении

Tags: c#, ооп, lambda, try-catch

у меня два вопроса :

1. как сделать метод Div() анонимным или лямбда .

2)при вызове метода Swap() выдаётся ошибка : CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'

```
using System;

namespace oopcalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        public class OopCalculator
        {
            private double num1;
            private double num2;
            public double Num1
            {
                get => num1;
                set => _ = num1;
            }
            public double Num2
            {
                get => num2;
                set => _ = num2;
            }

            public OopCalculator()
            {
            }

            public OopCalculator(double num1, double num2)
            {
                this.num1 = num1;
                this.num2 = num2;
            }

            public double Sum => this.num1 + this.num2;
            public double Sub => this.num1 + this.num2;
            public double Mul => this.num1 * this.num2;
            public double Div()
            {
                double temp = 0;
                try
                {
                    temp = this.num1 / this.num2;  
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                return temp;
            }
            public void Swap()
            {
                double temp = this.num1;
                this.num1 = this.num2;
                this.num2 = temp;

            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OopCalculator test = new OopCalculator
            {
                Num1 = 9,
                Num2 = 454
            };
            Console.WriteLine(test.Sum);
            Console.WriteLine(test.Sub);
            Console.WriteLine(test.Div());
            Console.WriteLine(test.Mul);
            Console.WriteLine(test.Swap());
            Console.WriteLine(test.Sum);
            Console.WriteLine(test.Sub);
            Console.WriteLine(test.Div());
            Console.WriteLine(test.Mul);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Что значит "как"? Также, как и обычные лямбды 2. Ну а что вы хотите вывести в данной строке `Console.WriteLine(test.Swap());`?

Comment: `set => _ = num1;` а вы уверены, что хотели это так написать?

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что вы хотите реализовать `Div` по аналогии с остальными операциями, тогда попробуй воспользоваться этим кодом:

```
public double Div
{
    get
    {
        double temp = 0;
        try
        {
            temp = this.num1 / this.num2;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

По поводу ошибки `CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'`
Дело в том, что функция `public void Swap()` не возвращает ничего: `void`. Ни нулевое значение, ни значение об отсутсвии какого либо значения, а вообще ничего не возращает. Это проблема, потому что функция `Console.WriteLine();` ожидает хоть какие либо данные в качестве аргумента. Попробуйте возращать значение в `Swap` если хотите сделать по анологии с остальными функциями то вот примерный код:

```
public string Swap
{
    get
    {
        double temp = this.num1;
        this.num1 = this.num2;
        this.num2 = temp;

        return "Swapped";
    }
}
```

Очевидно, что при использовании свойств скобки нужно будет убрать:

```
Console.WriteLine(test.Sum);
Console.WriteLine(test.Sub);
Console.WriteLine(test.Div);
Console.WriteLine(test.Mul);
Console.WriteLine(test.Swap);
Console.WriteLine(test.Sum);
Console.WriteLine(test.Sub);
Console.WriteLine(test.Div);
Console.WriteLine(test.Mul);
```

Comment: извините за мою тупость , непонимаю как я мог такое незаметить , спасибо вам